# Não ir para outro FORM1 enquanto FORM2 esiver aberto

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Suponhamos que tenha dois forms, o primeiro form1 é a tela principal ao qual dá uma opção de abrir outro form qualquer, quando esse form qualquer estiver aberto, o usuário não poderá ir para o form principal enquanto não encerrar/fechar o form2.

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você Pode utilizar o .ShowDialog();

Exemplo:

```
Form2 form=new Form2();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Enquanto o usuário não fechar a tela do Form2 não conseguirá fazer nada na tela do Form1

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Era justamente isso que estava precisando!